# Python subprocess Popen set encoding of the child process

Tags: python, windows, encoding, utf-8, subprocess

This SSCCE reports the encoding rule on sys.stdout. It works by creating a temporary Python file and running it via the subprocess module:

```
subp_code = "import sys\nprint(sys.stdout.encoding)"
test_fname = 'sub_test123123123_TMP.py' # I doubt anyone on Earth has an *important* file with this name.
with open(test_fname, 'w') as f:
    f.write(subp_code)

import os, sys, subprocess
pr = subprocess.Popen(['python', test_fname], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = pr.communicate()  # Use this for one-shot interaction. Do not use for processes that you want to have a back-and-forth conv with.
os.remove(test_fname) # Delete the tmp file we just made.
print('Encoding here:', sys.stdout.encoding) #utf-8
print('Encoding in subprocess:', out.decode().strip()) #cp1252 on Windows.
```

On windows the child process has cp1252 instead of utf-8 for whatever nonsense reason. This means unicode print statements that work under utf-8 generally won't work under cp1252:

```
print(chr(1234)) #UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u04d2' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Adding "encoding='utf-8'" to the Popen kwargs doesn't work: the subprocess ends up communicating in strings instead of binary (so you would have to remove the decode() call in the above example) but the child process is still under cp1252.

Within a subprocess it can be manually changed:

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

However I would like to not rely on adding that line of code to all of my subprocesses. Is there any way to configure the subprocess to use utf-8 std streams from the main process?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an env variable to the child process to control its I/O encoding:

```py
pr = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python', test_fname],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    env={'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'utf-8'},
)
```

Python sets the encoding of the standard I/O channels to some platform-dependent default using some heuristic, which involves inspecting its environment when the interpreter is started. The outcome depends on a number of factors, but if you want control, you can override the heuristic with the `PYTHONIOENCODING` variable (among other options).

By adding this env variable to the `Popen` call, you tell the Python interpreter in the child process to decode/encode with UTF-8 when reading from STDIN and writing to STDOUT/STDERR.
With `encoding='utf-8'` in the Popen call, however, you affect the other end of the pipes: with this you tell the parent process to decode the child's output with UTF-8 (and encode any input passed to it with the same codec).